# Issue with duplicates in Kafka consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Testing one Kafka message on partition 0 where the processing takes over an hour. I have tried auto commit, pause/resume, increase max poll timeout however I could not stop the consumer message duplication.
This is confluent kafka using python. I don't see a way to experiment async/sync commit.

```
        msg= self.consumer.poll(timeout=1.0)
            if msg:
                self.consumer.pause()
                some task.. (takes ~60 minutes minutes)
                self.consumer.resume()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(..)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your consumer is rebalancing, causing you to reprocess data. There's not much you can do from the consumer to prevent duplicates if you are getting at-least-once delivery.

You should update your task to lookup data, externally, by some identifier such that duplicates are ignored.